# How can I update an android FragmentPagerAdapter to show new set of data

Tags: android, image, fragmentpageradapter, android-pageradapter

I have a custom FragmentPagerAdapter that holds two ArrayLists sets of data:

```
private ArrayList<Uri> lockedUris   = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Uri> unlockedUris = new ArrayList<>();
```

The lockedUris is always an inclusive subset of unlockedUris .

My app uses unlockedUris to show a set of uri images using the FragmentPagerAdapter, one image per fragment.

The thing that I want to do is the following:

I want to switch from using unlockedUris to using lockedUris and then update all the FragmentPagerAdapter views in order to show the new set of images.
The way that I am currently changing from one uri Array to another is by checking a flag (isLocked) and returning one array or the other in each function of the FragmentPagerAdapter that uses them like the following:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition (Object object)
{
    PreviewFragment previewFragmentObject = (PreviewFragment) object;

    // Choose what Uris array to use on the comparison.
    ArrayList<Uri> tempUri = (isLocked)?lockedUris:unlockedUris;

    if (tempUri.contains(previewFragmentObject.getUri()))
    {
        Log.d("INFORMATION", "This Uri is part of the images array currently showing: "+previewFragmentObject.getUri());
        return tempUri.indexOf(previewFragmentObject.getUri());
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("INFORMATION", "This Uri is NOT part of the images array currently showing: "+previewFragmentObject.getUri());
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (isLocked)
    {
        return PreviewFragment.newInstance(lockedUris.get(position));
    } else
    {
        return PreviewFragment.newInstance(unlockedUris.get(position));
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (isLocked)
    {
        return lockedUris.size();
    } else
    {
        return unlockedUris.size();
    }
}

public Uri getUri(int position) {
   if(isLocked)
   {
       return lockedUris.get(position);
   }
   else
   {
       return unlockedUris.get(position);
   }
}
```

Of course I also want to be able to go back to using unlockedUris after toggling my flag back to normal.

Right now my app is capable of displaying all the Uris from unlockedUris inside the pager and I can swipe back and forth through all the images just fine, however when I switch to lockedUris (isLocked = true) the pager keeps the current image but the rest of images that should stay are not the same and usually a different subset from unlockedUris that is not equal to lockedUris.

I know that is hard to understand without code but please let me know what part of the code would be helpful to look at and I'll add it here, I don't want to add a big chunk of code that might not even be relevant to this problem (I am completely lost as to how the pager is working :s)

Comment: Why not use two different adapters?

Comment: I thought it would be better to just use one adapter and change its internal data set, it sounded more like the right solution to me first but do you think  that using two adapters would fix this problem and be a better design?

Comment: Adding a new fragment and changing between them helped with the fix, I also had to use FragmentStatePageAdapter to make sure that no previous fragments were kept and mistakenly used as part of the new array along with many other null checkings and exception catchings. Thanks for the help!